# Serialzed Objects Stored in File are not readable

Tags: java, serialization

The problem is that when I store Serialized Object in a .txt file it's not in readable form and contain some random symbols and letters. First of all I would like to know that what's the reason behind that and then how to solve this problem.

**Ok So here is my code: Object that I want to Serialize**

```
package serialized;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Student implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String s_name;
int roll_no;

public Student(String s_name, int roll_no){
    this.s_name=s_name;
    this.roll_no=roll_no;
}

public void getInfo(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+s_name+" Roll No: " + roll_no);
}
}
```

**Serialization**

```
package serialized;
import java.io.*;
public class StudentWriter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1=new Student("Asiya", 58);
    try{

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("abc.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        // Writing Object Info to File
        oos.writeObject(s1);
        System.out.println("Data has been written to file");
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**Deserialization**

```
package serialized;
import java.io.*;
public class StudentReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        // Reading Data from File
        Student s_data=(Student)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("Data has been read");
        s_data.getInfo();

        ois.close();
        fis.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

**Output:**

```
 ¬í sr serialized.Student        I roll_noL s_namet Ljava/lang/String;xp   :t      Asiya
```

Comment: I dont unserstand the -3... I just wanted to know that why output is appearing like this.

Comment: its working fine to me.. @SyedaNaqvi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Serialized Objects Stored in File are not readable

They aren't meant to be readable, other than via de-serialization.

> The problem is that when I store Serialized Object in a .txt file it's not in readable form and contain some random symbols and letters.

That's not a problem. The only problem is your misplaced expectation that it should be human-readable. There is no specification anywhere that says so.

> First of all I would like to know that what's the reason behind that

It is specified in the [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

> and then how to solve this problem.

What problem? Your code works correctly. The output in the dialog box put up by `StudentReader` is correct:

```
Name: Asiya Roll No: 58
```

What you have *clearly* done here is look directly into the serialized file with some utility program, rather than run your `StudentReader` program.

There is no problem here to solve.

NB:

1. Closing the object stream closes the underlying file stream. You don't need to close the file stream yourself.
2. Serialized objects are not text and should not be saved in .txt files.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into the txt file. Because my assignment is that: Serialized object should appear in proper format in the txt file.

Comment: Define 'proper format'. If you are being asked to use `Serialization` to produce a text file, let alone a readable text file, your assignment is completely nonsensical, as that is not what Serialization does. And if you're being asked to look in the text file, what is the purpose of the `StudentReader` class? It doesn't make sense. You need to review what your assignment actually says.

Comment: Well as i have defined already: Assignment is that: Why it's not in a human readable format in the .txt file?

Comment: I am unable to believe that you have interpreted your assignment correctly. Please post the exact wording in your question. It isn't human-readable because there is no specifcation anywhere that says it *should* be human-readable. I have provided a link in my answer which explains the format.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks for putting your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Serialized Objects (in Java) stored in a file are not meant to be readable by human eye. If you want to read the file, you need to do that with a Java program.

Comment: Isn't this a Java Program..?

Comment: @SyedaNaqvi Yes it is, but you didn't run it, did you?

Comment: I have run your program. It is able to read the data that you stored in the file. But if you open the file using notepad or any other text editor the contents are not meaningful to human eyes. Your program is hundred percent correct in reading serialized object from file.

Comment: Ofcourse I run this code. I never said that there is error in the code, I was asking about .txt file where the serialized object is stored. It's not in proper format there

Comment: @SyedaNaqvi It most certainly is in the 'proper format', and the fact that your reader code executes correctly proves it. The only problem here is your misplaced expectation.