# Java (Mac OS) : Writing my object to a file results in garbled test when re-reading the object from the file

Tags: eclipse, macos, serialization

I have written the [following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAxo4.png) using the Eclipse IDE.

When I open the txt file with gb18030,it is some of the test is garbled, as can be seen here:

[image: here]

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue?

Comment: First : please post the actual code and output in the question itself, not their images. Second - please post the code of your User class. You are dumping into an output file based on an unknown serialization/deserialization solution.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, because you are using `ObjectOutputStream`, try

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("path", false), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Check out the answer at [Serialzed Objects Stored in File are not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453437/serialzed-objects-stored-in-file-are-not-readable)
 
and [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)