# Java write to the file nonreadable sumbols

Tags: java

This is my method, he create new object "predmet". class "AddNewObject" return me predmet type (name, description).

```
AddNewPredmet addnewpredmet = new AddNewPredmet();
listPredmet.add(AddNewPredmet.AddPredmet());
StorageInFile.savePredmet(listPredmet);
```

All working. But I have a problem with the result written in the file. The output file has symbols that are not readable as shown -
`¬н sr java.util.ArrayListxЃТ™Зaќ I sizexp   w   sr entity.PredmetїБц)Зя| L Descriptiont Ljava/lang/String;L PNameq ~ xpt testt testx`

The following is the function that writes to the file

```
public class StorageInFile {
    static void savePredmet(List<Predmet> listPredmet) {
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
       try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream("Predmet.txt");
          oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
          oos.writeObject(listPredmet);
          oos.flush();
          oos.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(StorageInFile.class.getName())
           .log(Level.SEVERE, "Нет такого файла", ex);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(StorageInFile.class.getName())
           .log(Level.SEVERE, "Не могу записать", ex);
      }
   }}
```

How i can fix this? I think about method toString(), but i cant add this method to this code.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file? What did you expect to be in it?

Comment: What exact content do you expect to be in the "Predmet.txt" file? And why do you expect the content to be formatted this way? And why do you care about the content, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: You wrote the object using the default serialization to the file. This serialization is not text-only, but may contain binary data as well as meta-data as it is designed to be able to read in the data into an object again.

Comment: content in the file will be " String name, String Description" .About second Question, idk, because i do all this by template of my teacher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialzed Objects Stored in File are not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453437/serialzed-objects-stored-in-file-are-not-readable)

Comment: And if you just want to write text you can use PrintWriter object or FileWriter

Comment: Write of an object will contain binary data. This is object serialization.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Idk nothing about the serilizable modificator, and problem was at this. This is normal for serializable, he will be not readable) thx)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a buffered writer and use UTF-8 capable viewer to see the file. You are  trying to using a tool that assumes a one-byte encoding, such as the Windows-125x encodings. Notepad is an example of such a tool. So using the capable viewer you can look at it.

Also it would help to show what’s in  your file

Answer (score 0):

If you expected to print the contents of every instance of Predmet in the List<> then you could try the following.

- Implement to the toString() method in Class Predmet
- Try the following snippet to write to file.

  ```java
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("sample.txt");
  try {
    int size = listPredMet.size();
    for (int index =0; index < size; index++){
        writer.write(listPredMet.get(index).toString());
        writer.flush();
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
    writer.close()
  }
  ```